# Detect DVD Burners in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, detect, dvd-burning

Is there anyway to dectect available DVD burners in a windows system using c++? I know how to detect all available drives but I would like to be able to detect which ones have the ability to burn DVD media.

Comment: You need to at least specifiy an operating system...

Comment: This looks fairly interesting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163992.aspx

Comment: It should also be noted that starting with windows xp, there is a built in API for burning. Which may be able to do what you want and more.

Comment: @humbagumba  - I think he specified windows in the question, though I guess "a windows system" could refer to a generic windowing system.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the question didn't say windows before it was edited and if it did, I guess I need new glasses :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the Image Mastering API (IMAPI). To list the available devices you can use [`IDiscMaster::EnumDiscRecorders`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365397(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

::GetDriveType()
::GetVolumeInformation()

Are the two APIs that I know of that may get you what you need to know.

However, neither has a clear & obvious way of obtaining "is this DVD drive a recorder?"

Answer (score 0):

You can get `GET_MEDIA_TYPES` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363264.aspx) with respect of `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_TYPES_EX` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363413.aspx). You can use if like in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363147.aspx. Information from `GET_MEDIA_TYPES` has all information which you need.